# Rendering HTML inside double curly braces

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-pipe

I am using a pipe in an Ionic/Angular app that is transforming a text and returning a result with an html code.

This an example of how I am using my pipe:

```
<ion-label>
  <span>{{ text | mypipe: 'lo':'secondary' }}</span>
</ion-label>
```

The resulting HTML of the code within the double curls is as follows:

```
Loth<ion-text color='secondary'>lo</ion-text>rien
```

The problem is that upon execution, all I am seeing in my label is `Loth<ion-text color='secondary'>lo</ion-text>rien` instead of Loth**lo**rien with the colored portion of the text (i.e: 'lo')

Any idea why I am having this behavior and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Downvoters: Instead of a downvote without any known reason, a comment or an edit would be helpful to understand well the problem and have a question that could be more helpful to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**:

When you want to render html which contains angular components you have to create/compile them [dynamically in runtime](https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html).

Angular by default sanitizes anything that goes into the view. To display html in your template you have to use:

```
<span [innerHTML]="text | mypipe: 'lo':'secondary'"></span>
```

Your pipe should return `SafeHtml`:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'mypipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    public transform(value, params): SafeHtml {
        //do whatever your pipe does and then
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(somethingToReturn);
    }
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding).

You can also write a generic pipe, like in [this article](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b) and then just use it:

```
<span [innerHTML]="text | mypipe: 'lo':'secondary' | safe: 'html'"></span>
```

But since your markup contains another angular component, it wont work. It would work with standard `html` markup.
You want to look for a way how to not only render some `html` but to `compile` your template dynamically and create the resulting component dynamically. Something along [these lines](https://www.arka.com/blog/dynamically-generate-angular-components-from-external-html).

Comment: Thanks! It worked without the need of compiling the template dynamically

Comment: really? that's strange, i will try it myself too, cause we had requirements like these a year back

Comment: ok :) maybe it worked because the Ionic component `ion-text` implements something similar to what is pointed out by the article